# Flutter widget can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter

**Error** The instance member `widget` can't be accessed in an initializer.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
          final List<NameModel> nameModel;
          Home({Key key,this.nameModel}):super(key: key);
        
          
          @override
          _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
          
        }
        
        class _HomeState extends State<Home>with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
          
        
         
     final List <Widget>pagesList=[FirstPage(nameModel2:widget.nameModel),Center(child: Text("home1"),),Center(child: Text("home2"),)];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `widget` is only available after the creation of your `StatefulWidget` and your `State` classes.

So you can't directly use them in an `initializer` since it is an `instance` variable.

So instead, initialise your `pagesList` inside your `initState` function.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home>with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  List <Widget> pagesList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pagesList = [FirstPage(nameModel2: widget.nameModel), Center(child: Text("home1")), Center(child: Text("home2"))];
  }
```